# what is the image of the disk?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Consider two infinite opaque walls(planes) *A* and *B* separated by a distance *c*; A light emitting disk of radius *r* is placed parallel to the floor at a distance *d* from the wall B. Now a hole is punched at a height of h from the floor. What shape is the image of the disk formed on wall *A*?

---

*[this crude image shows the setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe2jE.png)

---

I tried to write the "process" as a complex function.
I got $f(x,y) = \frac{xc}{y-h} +i\frac{yh}{y-c}$

 where x and y is the position of a point on the floor with respect to *A*...
I still can't find a reasonable expression for the image.

Comment: The light emitting disc will form an oblique cone with the hole in wall B.  The intersection of this cone with wall A is an ellipse.

Comment: YESSS... that is what I was expecting... but how would we prove it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Place the center of coordinate system at the position of the hole. Now the horizontal plane has equation
$$H \colon z = - h$$

In this plane we have a circle of radius $r$ with center at the point $(r + d, 0, - h)$ ( if $d$ were $0$, then the circle touches the wall; in general it is at the distance $d$ to the right). The equation of the circle in this horizontal plane is

$$f(x,y) \colon = (x-(d+r))^2 + y^2 - r^2=0, \ \ z = -h$$

The equation of the cone determined by this curve is homogenous in $x$, $y$, $z$ ( that is, depends only on the ratios $\frac{x}{z}$, $\frac{y}{z}$, or $[x\colon y \colon z]$, and can be easily checked to be

$$f(\frac{-h x}{z}  , \frac{-h y}{z} ) = 0$$

Now to find the intersection of the cone with the vertical plane $x=-c$, plug in $x=-c$ in the above equation in $x$, $y$, $z$, and get an equation in $y$, $z$

$$f(\frac{-h (-c)}{z}, \frac{-h y}{z}) = 0$$

$\bf{Added:}$ Let's consider a numerical case: $h= 2$, $c = 3$, $d=1$, $r = 4$.

The equation of the circle in the horizontal plane $z= -2$ is

$$(x-(1+4))^2 + y^2 - 16 = 0$$
or
$$x^2 - 10 x + y^2 + 9 = 0$$

Now homogenize ( $x \mapsto \frac{-2 x}{z}$, $y\mapsto \frac{-2y}{z}$) and get the equation of the cone

$$4 x^2 + 20 x z + 4 y^2 + 9 z^2 = 0$$

Now plug in $x=- 3$ in the above.

$\bf{Added:}$ Explanation for the equation of the cone:  along a ray of the cone all of the points  have proportional coordinates. Hence the equation of the cone has to be of the form $F(\frac{x}{z}, \frac{y}{z})= 0$. Now the idea is to obtain an equation of this form from the equation $f(x,y)=0, \ \ z=-h$.  Substitute  $x$ with $\frac{-h}{z} \cdot x$ ( note that the fraction is $1$ on the plane $z=-h$), and similarly for $y$.

Comment: Well done [+1] This is by far a better approach to the problem than my approach.

Comment: @Hosam Hajjir:  Thank you!  We all are learning bit by bit :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let the coordinate system attached to the set up have its origin at the center of the light emitting disk, with its $x$ axis perpendicular to the two parallel walls.  Then the equation of wall $B$ is $ x = - d $ and of wall $A$ is $ x = - d - c $.  The hole is at $H = (- d , 0, h ) $

The parametric equation of the boundary of the disk is

$ \mathbf{P}(t) = r(\cos t , \sin t , 0 ) = \cos(t) (r, 0, 0) + \sin(t) (0, r, 0) \hspace{25pt} (1)$

The hole together with the boundary of the disk will form an oblique cone whose

parametric (vector) equation is

$ \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{H} = s ( \mathbf{P}(t) - \mathbf{H} ) = s M \mathbf{v} \hspace{25pt}(2) $

where

$ M = \begin{bmatrix} r && 0 && - d \\ 0 && r && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && h \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt}(3)$

and

$ \mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos t \\ \sin t \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt}(4) $

One can easily verify that

$\mathbf{v}^T Q_0 \mathbf{v} = 0 \hspace{25pt}(5)$

where

$ Q_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && -1 \end{bmatrix}\hspace{25pt}(6)$

Solving for $\mathbf{v}$ from equation $(2)$, we get

$ \mathbf{v} = \dfrac{1}{s} M^{-1} (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{H}) \hspace{25pt}(7)$

Substitute that in equation $(5)$, gives us the algebraic equation of the cone

$ (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{H}) M^{-T} Q_0 M^{-1} (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{H}) = 0 \hspace{25pt} (8)$

We now have to intersect this cone with the plane of wall $A$ whose equation is

$ x = - d - c \hspace{25pt} (9)$

To that end, let's calculate $M^{-1}$ first, using the fact that

$M^{-1} = \dfrac{ \text{adj}(M) }{\det(M)} \hspace{25pt} (10) $

we have

$ M^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{r} && 0 && \dfrac{d}{rh} \\ 0 && \dfrac{1}{r} && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && \dfrac{1}{h} \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt}(11) $

So that

$ Q = M^{-T} Q_0 M^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{r^2} && 0 && \dfrac{d}{r^2 h} \\ 0 && \dfrac{1}{r^2} && 0 \\ \dfrac{d}{r^2 h} && 0 && \dfrac{d^2 - r^2}{r^2 h^2} \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt} (12) $

Now the plane of wall $A$ can be represented parametrically (vector equation)

$ \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r_0} + y \ \mathbf{j} + z \ \mathbf{k} = \mathbf{r_0} + V \mathbf{u} \hspace{25pt}(13)$

where $\mathbf{j}$ and $\mathbf{k}$ are the unit vectors in the $y$ and $z$ directions, respectively, $\mathbf{r_0} = (- d - c, 0, 0 ) $ , and

$ V = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 \\ 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

$ \mathbf{u} = [y, z ]^T $

Substituting $(13)$ into equation $(8)$ results in

$ (\mathbf{r_1} + V \mathbf{u} )^T Q (\mathbf{r_1} + V \mathbf{u} )  = 0 \hspace{25pt}(14) $

where

$\mathbf{r_1} = \mathbf{r_0} - \mathbf{H} = (- c , 0 , - h ) \hspace{25pt} (15) $

Expanding terms in equation $(14)$

$ \mathbf{r_1}^T Q \mathbf{r_1} + 2 \mathbf{u}^T V^T Q \mathbf{r_1} + \mathbf{u}^T V^T Q V \mathbf{u} = 0 \hspace{25pt}(16)$

Evaluating all the terms, we end up with the quadratic equation,

$ \mathbf{u}^T Q_e \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{u}^T b_e + c_e = 0\hspace{25pt}(17) $

where

$Q_e = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{r^2} && 0 \\ 0 && \dfrac{d^2 - r^2}{r^2 h^2} \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt}(18a)$

$ b_e = -2 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \dfrac{ c d + d^2 - r^2}{r^2 h} \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt}(18b)$

$ c_e = \dfrac{(c + d)^2 - r^2 }{r^2}\hspace{25pt}(18c) $

To complete the analysis, we find the center of this $2D$ conic as follows

$\mathbf{u_C} = -\dfrac{1}{2} Q_e^{-1} b_e = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ h \bigg(1+ \dfrac{cd}{d^2 - r^2} \bigg) \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt}(19)$

Now the equation of the conic can be written as

$ (\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u_C} )^T Q_e (\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u_C} ) = \mathbf{u_C}^T Q_e \mathbf{u_C} - c_e \hspace{25pt}(20) $

The right hand side of $(20)$ is

$\mathbf{u_C}^T Q_e \mathbf{u_C} - c_e = \dfrac{c^2 }{d^2 - r^2 } = K^2 \hspace{25pt} (21) $

Since the right-hand side of $(20)$ is positive, and $Q_e$ is positive definite, we deduce that the conic is an ellipse, whose equation is

$ (\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u_C} )^T Q_e (\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u_C} ) = K^2 $

Since $Q_e$ is diagonal, the semi-axes of the ellipse are, respectively,

along the $y$ direction,

$ S_{\text{Horizontal}} =K r = \dfrac{c r}{\sqrt{d^2 - r^2}}$

and along the $z$ direction,

$ S_{\text{Vertical}} =\dfrac{ K r h }{\sqrt{d^2 - r^2}} = h \dfrac{c r}{d^2 - r^2}  $

Comment: I wonder if there is a geometric way to find the foci of the ellipse on the vertical plane.  Also, in which cases the ellipse is again a circle. Interesting problem.

Comment: @orangeskid   From the expressions for the semi-axes, the ellipse on wall A will be a circle if $h = \sqrt{d^2 - r^2} $

Comment: Wow, that is very interesting!

Comment: @orangeskid Glad you liked it.

Comment: Your approach with the quadratic form is very neat.  We can start with the cone ( a given quadratic form) and compare the different intersections with either of the planes $x=1$, $y=1$, $z=1$..  Perhaps something to do with the principal $2\times 2$ minors.   I wonder what happens when the plane is oblique. How to get the shape in that case.

Comment: You just have to parametrize the plane, and write in explicit parametric vector form as $r = r_0 + V u $ where the two columns of $V$ are mutually orthogonal unit vectors that are also orthogonal to the normal of the plane.  The rest of the solution is the same, except in the general case, the off-diagonal entries of $Q_e$ are in general not zero, and we have to diagonalize $Q_e$.  The formula for the ellipse center still holds.